# How to compare CPU speeds

Tags: 11.10, cpu

I found this attribute called "BogoMips" (Bogus Millions of Instructions per Second) while doing `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and after seeing the definition:

```
The number of million times per second a processor can do absolutely nothing
```

I was left with the question, how can I know, preferably by terminal, which CPU is faster or can process more per second given the Cache, CPU Mhz and other properties that can affect the speed or process of it.

In my case I have 2 laptops:

The AMD is a Turion(tm) 64 X2 Mobile Technology TL-60 - Gave me 4001.06 bogomips

and the Intel is an Intel Core 2 Duo T550 - Gave me 3326.05 bogomips.

I mention again the bogomips since it was the only "form of measure" I found when running the command but just to see if anybody has a command for this it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Phoronix Test Suite

```
OpenBenchmarking.org Integration
130+ Test Profiles
60+ Test Suites
Extensible Testing Architecture
Optional Linux-based LiveDVD/USB Testing Distribution (PTS Desktop Live)
Automated Test Installation
Dependency Management Support
Module-based Plug-In Architecture
PNG, JPG, GIF, Adobe SWF, SVG Graph Rendering Support
Automated Batch Mode Support
Global Database For Result Uploads, Benchmark Comparisons
Detailed Software, Hardware Detection
System Monitoring Support
GTK2 Graphical User Interface + Command-Line Interface
Runs On Linux, OpenSolaris, Mac OS X, Windows 7, & BSD Operating Systems
```

[image]

- [Home page](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=home)
- [Download](http://phoronix-test-suite.com/releases/repo/pts.debian/files/phoronix-test-suite_3.6.1_all.deb)

Answer (score 3):

This is not *„the terminal way”*, but you can look the processors up on [cpubenchmark.net](http://cpubenchmark.net/). It will give you an approximate value how well their benchmark performs on the selected processors. There is a page on [how they test](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_test_info.html).

- AMD Turion 64 X2 Mobile TL-60: **994 points**
- Intel Core2 Duo T5500 @ 1.66GHz: **925 points**

According to the readings, they have roughly the same power and both play in the *„Low Mid Range CPUs League”*.

Comment: Well I am looking for a terminal way or at least a GUI if there is no terminal but the web page you linked has some serious benchmarks. That is a very long list.